# Highchart error#15 on trying to plot seperated vertical lines

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a series visually similar to plot lines. I can't use plotline feature as I need support for tooltips and other related features.

Even after ordering the data, I get the error/warning#15. The problem is that the timeseries labels for the x-axis dissapears due to this error. The labels show up when just one vertical line(2 points) are present. When I add the next line(2 set of 2-points seperated by a null), then I get the error, and the x-axis labels dissapear.

I have a kpi spline on my primary y-axis. This is meant to be a secondary axis.

Single line - https://jsfiddle.net/cLs6x85b/

Two lines - https://jsfiddle.net/xfd6ruv5/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
type: 'spline',
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: [{
            // secondary axis
            name: 'secondary-axis-events',
            tickPositions: [0, 1],
           
        }],
series: [{
    name: 'test',
    data: [
      {y: 0, x: 1545361356415},
      {y: 1, x: 1545361356415},
      null,
      {y: 0, x: 1545361356417},
      {y: 1, x: 1545361356417}
    ],
    color: '#7fdbed'
}]
}, (chart) => {
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1545361356413, 1545361356419);
});
```

nb: I have tried scatter and its still the same result.

I am fine to ignore the error/warning. The missing x-axis labels is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the getting error and rendering the xAxis labels properly you need to keep your x data sequence, that's mean that the separator data should be an object with defined x and y set as null.

```
  data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: 1545361356415
    },
    {
      y: 1,
      x: 1545361356415
    },
    {
      y: null,
      x: 1545361356416
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: 1545361356417
    },
    {
      y: 1,
      x: 1545361356417
    }
  ],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/84fqm1Lp/

1. Have you considered to use the `Lollipop` series? Demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/lollipop
2. I think that setting the `findNearestPointBy` to `xy` could be an interesting feature for your case: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.findNearestPointBy